# How to pass argument to cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to pass parameters to cypher query?

```
match (n{})-[r]-(m) where ID(n)=? return n,r,m
```

Here is code where I implemented, but no luck.

```
session.run('match (n)-[r]-(m) where ID(n)={nodeID} return n,r,m', {nodeID : 
nodes}).then(function (result)
```

Comment: The variable `nodes` is an array of identifiers?

Comment: Di you have an error when you execute this query ? If so what is the error ? FYI your implentation is correct, except that the way you declare a parameter in your query : {myVar} is deprecated, you should use $myVar instead.

Comment: Yes, i have changed method $nodeID instead of {nodeID} but it is not working.But no error and nothing returns. But if hardcode value that works fine.

Comment: so it must be a problem of type .. are you sure that `nodes` is an integer ?  Otherwise can you add `toInteger($nodeId)` in your query ?